# ¿Cómo desplegar en Android Studio ubicación actual en MapFragment? (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy manejando una app con Bottom Navigation, la cual al presionar uno de los tres botones despliega un fragmento con un mapa. Hago hincapié en que se trata de un **fragmento** y **no de una actividad**. La MainActivity solamente gestiona la función del **menú bottom navigation**. Actualmente funciona correctamente, pero quiero que el mapa que se despliega contenga la ubicación actual del usuario y no sólo despliegue un mapa predeterminado.

**MapFragment**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private static MapFragment INSTANCE = null;

    View view;
    GoogleMap map;
    MapView mapView;

    public MapFragment(){ }

    public static MapFragment getINSTANCE() {
        if(INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new MapFragment();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapsView);

        if(mapView != null){
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        map = googleMap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo ando en las mismas y he visto que es necesario usar FusedLocationProviderClient y de esta manera poder mostrar la ubicacion actual y no un punto en el mapa.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

Answer (score 0):

Después de todo lo pude resolver. Primeramente se tienen que gestionar los permisos de localización, por lo que se tiene que añadir lo siguiente en **Manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Finalmente anexo el código dentro del fragmento. Reitero que se trata de una app que tiene un menú **Bottom Navigation**, por lo que lo siguiente va dentro de un **Fragment** correspondiente a uno de los botónes y no en el **MainActivity**:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_INT = 177;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.mapsView);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        return mView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;


        // Verificar permisos de localización.

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            //Código para permiso no concedido.

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_INT);
            }

            return;

        } else {


            //Código para permiso concedido.

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            getLastLocation();

            // Código para añadir marcador en el mapa

            LatLng bar1 = new LatLng(32.533890,-117.037507);
            LatLng bar2 = new LatLng(32.514054,-117.031813);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bar1).title("Mamut (Calle 3ra)").snippet("Aquí se sirve la cerveza #1"));
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bar2).title("Cervecería Tijuana (Fundadores)").snippet("Aquí se sirve la cerveza #2"));


        }


    }

    public void getLastLocation() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        try {
            locationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // GPS location can be null if GPS is switched off
                            if (location != null) {
                                if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),15));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("MapDemoActivity", "Error trying to get last GPS location");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
``
```